I can't compile my app as a single executable
I'm trying to compile my C# application as a single-file executable. I can compile it, but if I move the executable file to any other location except the build folder, it can't be started and shows error.
I followed all the tips I could google. Now my .csproj file looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

And the compilation command looks like:
dotnet publish -c Release -p:PublishReadyToRun=true

Then I can start it with
rpr@latita:~/MyApp$ ./bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/MyApp 
Hello, World!

But if I copy this file with command cp ./bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/MyApp ~/MyAppExecutable and then start it with command ~/MyAppExecutable it shows the following error:

The application to execute does not exist: '/home/rpr/MyApp.dll'.

How can I fix a missing DLL error and make a single-file executable?
Here is content of the publish directory (/home/rpr/MyApp/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/):
/home/rpr/MyApp/bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64
├── createdump
├── libclrgc.so
├── libclrjit.so
├── libcoreclr.so
├── libcoreclrtraceptprovider.so
├── libhostfxr.so
├── libhostpolicy.so
├── libmscordaccore.so
├── libmscordbi.so
├── libSystem.Globalization.Native.so
├── libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.so
├── libSystem.Native.so
├── libSystem.Net.Security.Native.so
├── libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so
├── Microsoft.CSharp.dll
├── Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll
├── Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
├── Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
├── Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
├── mscorlib.dll
├── MyApp
├── MyApp.deps.json
├── MyApp.dll
├── MyApp.pdb
├── MyApp.runtimeconfig.json
├── netstandard.dll
├── publish
│   ├── MyApp
│   └── MyApp.pdb
├── System.AppContext.dll
├── System.Buffers.dll
├── System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
├── System.Collections.dll
├── System.Collections.Immutable.dll
├── System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
├── System.Collections.Specialized.dll
├── System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
├── System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
├── System.ComponentModel.dll
├── System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
├── System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
├── System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
├── System.Configuration.dll
├── System.Console.dll
├── System.Core.dll
├── System.Data.Common.dll
├── System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
├── System.Data.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
├── System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
├── System.dll
├── System.Drawing.dll
├── System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
├── System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
├── System.Formats.Asn1.dll
├── System.Formats.Tar.dll
├── System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
├── System.Globalization.dll
├── System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
├── System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll
├── System.IO.Compression.dll
├── System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
├── System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
├── System.IO.dll
├── System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
├── System.IO.FileSystem.dll
├── System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll
├── System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
├── System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
├── System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll
├── System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll
├── System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll
├── System.IO.Pipes.dll
├── System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
├── System.Linq.dll
├── System.Linq.Expressions.dll
├── System.Linq.Parallel.dll
├── System.Linq.Queryable.dll
├── System.Memory.dll
├── System.Net.dll
├── System.Net.Http.dll
├── System.Net.Http.Json.dll
├── System.Net.HttpListener.dll
├── System.Net.Mail.dll
├── System.Net.NameResolution.dll
├── System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
├── System.Net.Ping.dll
├── System.Net.Primitives.dll
├── System.Net.Quic.dll
├── System.Net.Requests.dll
├── System.Net.Security.dll
├── System.Net.ServicePoint.dll
├── System.Net.Sockets.dll
├── System.Net.WebClient.dll
├── System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
├── System.Net.WebProxy.dll
├── System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
├── System.Net.WebSockets.dll
├── System.Numerics.dll
├── System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
├── System.ObjectModel.dll
├── System.Private.CoreLib.dll
├── System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
├── System.Private.Uri.dll
├── System.Private.Xml.dll
├── System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll
├── System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll
├── System.Reflection.dll
├── System.Reflection.Emit.dll
├── System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
├── System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
├── System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
├── System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
├── System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
├── System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
├── System.Resources.Reader.dll
├── System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
├── System.Resources.Writer.dll
├── System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
├── System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll
├── System.Runtime.dll
├── System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
├── System.Runtime.Handles.dll
├── System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
├── System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll
├── System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
├── System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
├── System.Runtime.Loader.dll
├── System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
├── System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
├── System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
├── System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
├── System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
├── System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
├── System.Security.AccessControl.dll
├── System.Security.Claims.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
├── System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
├── System.Security.dll
├── System.Security.Principal.dll
├── System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
├── System.Security.SecureString.dll
├── System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
├── System.ServiceProcess.dll
├── System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
├── System.Text.Encoding.dll
├── System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
├── System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
├── System.Text.Json.dll
├── System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
├── System.Threading.Channels.dll
├── System.Threading.dll
├── System.Threading.Overlapped.dll
├── System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
├── System.Threading.Tasks.dll
├── System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
├── System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
├── System.Threading.Thread.dll
├── System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
├── System.Threading.Timer.dll
├── System.Transactions.dll
├── System.Transactions.Local.dll
├── System.ValueTuple.dll
├── System.Web.dll
├── System.Web.HttpUtility.dll
├── System.Windows.dll
├── System.Xml.dll
├── System.Xml.Linq.dll
├── System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
├── System.Xml.Serialization.dll
├── System.Xml.XDocument.dll
├── System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
├── System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
├── System.Xml.XPath.dll
├── System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
└── WindowsBase.dll


Are you sure the file you moved is the correct one?

You haven't given us enough information. What is the name of the application that you're trying to execute? How are you starting it? Does it depend on a DLL?

What are the contents of the publish folder?

@shingo I copy file ./bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/MyApp. I added that to the question.

@JimMischel Thanks, I updated the question with your questions in mind.

@PMF The question is updated with the publish folder content list

That publish folder doesn't look like the output of a single file publish. There should be only an executable in there.

If you're copying just the file MyApp to your home directory and then running it, it seems unreasonable to expect Linux to find the DLL that it depends on if you don't tell it where that DLL is. This sounds like an issue with where Linux expects executables and shared libraries to be, where it searches for them, etc. Hopefully somebody else can give you the particulars of that ('cause I'm not 100% sure about it). If that's indeed the problem. Your question is still unclear.

It looks like the problem was that I used the file ./bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/MyApp to share. Now I use the file ./bin/Release/net8.0/linux-x64/publish/MyApp (publish added inside the path) for sharing, and the problem disappeared.
